# Export ListView to Excel (Cell colors)?

Tags: c#, listview

I am using the following method to export my ListView to Excel:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        app.Visible = true;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
        int i = 1;
        int i2 = 1;
        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
        {
            i = 1;
            foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvs in lvi.SubItems)
            {
                ws.Cells[i2, i] = lvs.Text;
                i++;
            }
            i2++;
        }
```

In my ListView i have set background colors for each cell, i want these colors to export over to Excel as well. The method above works perfectly but does not include the color in the export.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Do you must use MS Office Interop Excel to do that? If so, it will be more auickly to get answer if you put it on MSDN forum. If not, I know a free tool that can completely statisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these posts it will help you: [Export to Excel with Grid Color in Winforms using C#](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code1071-export-to-excel-with-grid-color-in-winforms-using-csharp.aspx)

[Retain cell background colour when exporting GridView to Excel](http://forums.asp.net/t/1648977.aspx)